# how to unit test an angular directive that binds to scroll

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I have an angular directive that returns the scroll top attribute of the element on the scroll event, but I'm having some problems unit testing it.

How do I mock a scroll event so that the scrollTop attribute is changed?

```
angular
  .module('app')
  .directive('scrollTop', scrollTop);

/** @ngInject */
function scrollTop() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      scroll: '=scrollTop'
    },
    link: function (scope, element) {
      element.bind('scroll', function () {
        scope.scroll = element[0].scrollTop;
      });
    }
  };
}

describe('tests for scroll top directive', function () {
  beforeEach(module('app'));

  it('should make the scrollTop of the element available', angular.mock.inject(function ($rootScope, $compile) {
    $rootScope.scroll = 0;
    var element = $compile('<div style="height: 1px;width: 5px;" scroll-top="scroll"></div>')($rootScope);
    $rootScope.$digest();
    element.css({scrollTop: 100})
    element.triggerHandler('scroll');
    expect($rootScope.scroll).toEqual(100);
  }));
});
```

Comment: I am afraid some of the scroll related stuff might not work on phantomJS browser

Comment: yes, I should have added this is being testing in PhantomJS